# Flutter: How to remove a specific array value in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In flutter, I want to Delete matching array value from the firebase Database.
[Here How the database look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDEkL.png)
From there I want to delete array `code` value that matches input data.
When user Pressed button I want to delete the array value in firebase Database.

```
TextFormField(
 style:
 labelText: 'CONFIRM',
 onChanged: (val) {
 setState(() {
    confirmCode = val; //user input val
  });
 },
),

RaisedButton(
onPressed: () async {                                          
 //here i want make a request to firebase to Delete
},
 child: Text('CONFIRM'),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the value from the array, then try the following:

```
onPressed: () async {
var clientCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("client");
clientCollection.document("confirmCode").updateData({
  "code" : FieldValue.arrayRemove([int.parse(confirmCode)])
}).then((_) {
  print("success!");
});                                          
},
```

Using `FieldValue.arrayRemove` you can delete an item from the array.

Comment: Now i figure it out. i change to int.parse(confirm).